# If i use the redshift copy command with a file prefix, how can I know the files it grabbed?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I want to use the copy command with a file prefix from a lambda to grab a bunch of files from S3 and dump them into redshift. When I do that, I want to know the list of files that got pulled so I can archive them off after the operation is completed. Is there a way to get the list of files that were executed against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [STL_LOAD_COMMITS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_COMMITS.html):

```
select * from stl_load_commits
```

Specify your condition, maybe `curtime` as your timestamp or parse filename.

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.